# Setting the value/text of event.target with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<a class="small" href="/comments/new">Write New Comment</a>
```

And the following js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {                                               
   $('.comment > a').click( function (event) {                                
         var url = event.target.href                                          
         $('.comment_area').load(url)                                         
          **event.target.text = ""**
          event.preventDefault()                                              
       })                                                                     
   })
```

I am trying to set the text of the link to blank, but can't seem to find a way to do this. I've also tried:

```
event.target.text("")
event.target.value = ""
```

and none of these work. Is this even possible to do from the JavaScript side?

Comment: Please read the [jQuery tutorial about basic event handling](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/): *"In addition to the event object, the event handling function also has access to the DOM element that the handler was bound to via the keyword `this`. To turn the DOM element into a jQuery object that we can use jQuery methods on, we simply do `$( this )`"*. Tutorials are great, they help a lot! You should read them!

Comment: From everything I've been reading, it's kind of ambiguous when to use event.target, vs $(this)...since $(this) could also refer to the surrounding DOM element, whereas event.target refers to the element that was actually clicked on.

Comment: `this` refers to the element the handler is bound to (unless you use jQuery's event delegation mechanism). In any case, this page also mentions that `event.target` is *"the DOM element that initiated the event"*. And the part I quoted says that we pass DOM elements (e.g. `this`) to `$` (e.g. `$(this)`), to create a jQuery object. I'm just saying that all the information is there, you just have to put the pieces together :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use `this`.

```
$('.comment > a').click( function (event) {
    $(this).text(""); 

    //Other stuff
});
```

You don't have to use `event.target`

`this` refers to the element which you have attached the event. In your case, `$('.comment > a')`

If you have multiple anchor links directly under the container `.comment`, it helps to differentiate between them & you could do specific things with each of those anchor links.

Comment: Could you also explain what `this` is and why it has to be passed to jQuery?

Comment: @FelixKling - sure will do.

Answer (score 0):

To set the text to blank use this method `.text('')`.

So, you method would change to the following one:

```
$(document).ready(function () {                                               
   $('.comment > a').click( function (event) {                                
      var url = event.target.href;
      // this can be replaced by the following
      var url = $(this).attr('href');
      $('.comment_area').load(url);                       
      $(this).text(''); // empty the current string
      event.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

It is better practice to add `;` at the end of the code lines! :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean so it disappears? You could do:

```
$(this).hide();
```

or

```
$(this).text("");
```

Comment: This would affect **all** anchors directly in the `.comment` element, not just the one clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery so why stick with Javascript alone?

```
$(document).ready(function () {                                               
   $('.comment > a').click( function (event) {                                
         $this = $(this);
         var url = $this.attr('href');
         $('.comment_area').load(url)                                         
          $this.text("");
          event.preventDefault()                                              
       })                                                                     
   })
```

This will save you the headaches of different event structure in different browsers

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
event.target.innerHTML = "";
```

or

```
event.currentTarget.innerHTML = "";
```

or

```
this.innerHTML = "";
```

`event.target` is the very first element on the top of the DOM. It mean that if there is a span in your `a`, the span will be selected.

That's why using `currentTarget` is safer since it is the element on which the event is binded.

`this` by default is the same as `currentTarget` but this value can be altered by `.apply()`, `.call()` or `.bind`.